# Llevar archivos en Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android-studio

Un favor enorme... comencé mi aventura en Android, pero tengo dudas, al llevar mi proyecto en Android Studio(por mas simple que sea este) veo que se crea una carpeta que pesa entre 40 a 50 MB... la duda es la siguiente:

- Para ejecutar mi avance en otra PC... siempre debo llevar todo el proyecto
- Hay alguna forma u orientación para solo llevar los archivos necesarios

Espero respuesta y me puedan ayudar..

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar el CSV Git, es como una manera de trabajar en local y en la nube (tu propio espacio público o privado) en diferentes espacios de tiempo (como si fueran backups) sincronizando tus cambios en los espacios de tiempo que quieras. Más y MEJOR información en: https://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa carpeta que mencionas pesa entre 40 y 50 Mb, en ocasiones puede pesar mucho mas.

La carpeta es `/build`, si deseas copiar el proyecto puedes eliminar los folders `/build` de tu proyecto ya que no son necesarios y se generan nuevamente al construir tu proyecto, con esto obtendras un peso muy pequeño de tu proyecto comparado al contener estos directorios.

Te acosejo tambien si trabajas en un equipo, poder usar un versionador como GIT o Subversion, donde estos directorios no necesarios pueden ser ignorados.

Comment: Muchas gracias... eso quería saber...